Forgot to pay Gatwick Dropoff Charge
I dropped my daughter off at Gatwick and completely forgot to pay the drop-off charge. It was due by midnight last night. I went on to their website this afternoon where is asks you to enter your registration number. I entered my registration number and it came back with this - "Sorry we have been unable to identify your vehicle".
I'm just wondering if I can still expect to receive a PCN though the post?
UPDATE 1: Well it's now nearly 4 weeks later and so far nothing. My understanding is they have to notify you within 14 days. So, guessing they didn't get my number plate when I stopped.
UPDATE 2: 15th Dec 2024 - After hearing nothing I've just got a letter through the post from a debt recovery company claiming that I had ignored the PCN (Which I didn't get) and that they had previously contacted me regarding this matter (Which they hadn't) and telling me that I owe them £170! So there you go!
UPDATE 3: I contacted NCP and they revoked the ticket from the debt recovery company and reissued the original PCN. I still had to pay £60 but it's better than £170.

Please come back and let us know what, if anything, happens.

@badjohn There you go, updated

Yes.
From London Gatwick drop off charges:

If you forget to pay by midnight the following day, you will be issued with a Parking Charge Notice (PCN).


Do the Draconians not even issue a final deadline notice? It's easy to overlook camera controlled parking and tolls when you are focused on other matters. Note that a 'Parking Charge Notice' is not a fine, and can only be enforced in the civil courts. OTOH a public parking infringment is served with a 'Penalty Charge Notice' which is a statutory fine.

@WeatherVane Hmmm, dropping off family at Gatwick is fairly memorable unless one does it so frequently the trips blur into one. There are no barriers at the drop off zones, ‘I forgot to pay’ must be one of the top appeal excuses. Setting up an autopay account before driving to the airport seems like a good idea.

Just wondering though why I go the message about not being able to identify my vehicle.

@Shazoo - just yesterday, I read this consumer complaint in The Guardian where a driver received multiple Dartford Crossing PCNs after the website reported "no crossing to be paid". Seems a number of these systems have issues.

@Traveller exactly: there are no barriers. If it's the first time someone has ever dropped the family it might not even occur to them that they will be fleeced just for dropping off. They might easily overlook the signs in all the uncertainty of what to do. The management seem very keen to make money off it, and perhaps Shazoo can't get the vehicle identified because it's too late to pay: a PCN is on its way.

@WeatherVane Yes that's what I thought, maybe they withdrew the identification because it's too late :-(

@Traveller it would seem they didn't send a PCN after all
